# Dropping the extra dimension after turning a RGB image to a grayscale image (100,100,3) -> (100,100,1) or (100,100)?

Tags: python, image, numpy, matplotlib

I'm working with numpy array images, and sometimes choose to convert to grayscale. Should I keep the extra dimension or drop it? **What are the benefits of working with an image (say with width/height of 100/100) that's shape = (100,100,1) VS. shape = (100,100)?**

Comment: You'll find `(100,100)` more convenient most of the time, probably. But it's trivial to switch back and forth, since you can just `.reshape`, this won't even copy the array.

Comment: It of course depends on what you plan to do. Maybe (we don't know what exactly you are doing) it's a good idea to use scikit-image which is pretty good at keeping these things well-defined (especially the float vs. uint8 stuff).